# push notification recipe in WCF for multiple WP7 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I want to use Microsoft's Push Notification recipe for my several WP7 apps.  Looking for some guidance on how I should create the WCF service and the database design so that all my WP7 apps can use the same WCF service to achieve Push Notification functionality.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/pnhelp-wp7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that design if you have all the apps having same set of users. But I'll recommend you to add a column to determine to which application the User belongs to. You can then create 2 Services, one for Subscription (that again takes the ApplicationId as a param) which you can use to subscribe/unsubscribe the users and another for Publishing Notifications, which can take ApplicationId if you want to send same notfication across all users or UserId if you want to send notification to particular user.